# Whonix workstation + Whonix gateway vs Kali + Whonix gateway

Tags: whonix, kali-linux

I see a lot of people using Kali and Whonix gateway instead of the original Whonix workstation and gateway. Why would they do that? What are the differences and are there any pros/cons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kali is an linux distribution particularly used by penetration testers. The default workstation is not by default configured to use as a pentesting platform. I suppose those who use kali behind a Whonix gateway wants to be anonymous while performing penetration tests.